# Non-Linear Regression Analysis (High School Math)

Tags: analysis, regression

I need to conduct some non-linear regression analysis on some data I have.

I have all the data points and a curve that fits but I want to find the accuracy of the curve, hence I need to conduct non-linear regression analysis.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. Is there something similar to r^2 for non-linear regression? I've done some research but it seems too complicated.

If there is a way to do this within excel that would be better but any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you know the curve it is supposed to fit you could do a substitution/ change of variables to change to a linear relationship and then do the usual linear regression analysis

Comment: When you say substitution/change of variables, do you mean linearizing it by putting the data points to a power/ln etc?

Comment: Yes, so if the curve is of the form $y=kx^n$ then $\ln y=\ln k+n\ln x$ gives a linear relationship between new variables $\ln y$ and $\ln x$, for example